# Is there any handy method to enumerate and invoke tests of a XCTestCase class in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, xctest

There is a class which provides a set of initXXX methods and some functional methods. It is handy to invoke all the functional tests at runtime when verifying the instance created by all these initXXX methods.

Just like this:

```
-(void) testEverythingWithInitXXX {
   if ( test of self.tests not postfix by 'WithInit.*' ) {
      invoke it.
   }
}
```

It is always possible by inspecting the ObjC object at runtime, I'm just wondering if Apple provided any help already in XCTest framework?

-- update --

I just found something.

```
NSArray * tests = [FileLibraryTests testInvocations];
for (NSInvocation * inv in tests ) {
    NSString * sel = NSStringFromSelector(inv.selector);
    if (![sel containsString:@"WithInit"]) {
        [inv invokeWithTarget:self];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this (using runtime you can fetch all methods from your class)

```
    void DumpObjcMethods(Class clz) {

        unsigned int methodCount = 0;
        Method *methods = class_copyMethodList(clz, &methodCount);

        printf("Found %d methods on '%s'\n", methodCount, class_getName(clz));

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < methodCount; i++) {
            Method method = methods[i];
        SEL customSelector = NSSelectorFromString([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", class_getName(clz)]);
         [self performSelector:customSelector withObject:nil];


            /**
             *  Or do whatever you need here...
             */
        }

    free(methods);
}
```

if you want to perform only some special method - check prefix via NSString method

```
 if ([methodStringRepresentation hasPrefix:@"init"])
    {
        // perform selector
    }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, but as I mentioned, I'm trying avoid this way.